# Loop through react to set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a event Handler in react to set the state on 10 items, what is the best way to set this out with out repeat this.state.

```
handleOpacityThermatic(event) {
    if (event == 0.1) { this.setState({ opacityValue: 0.1, opacityName: '10%' }); }
    if (event == 0.2) { this.setState({ opacityValue: 0.2, opacityName: '20%' }); }
    if (event == 0.3) { this.setState({ opacityValue: 0.3, opacityName: '30%' }); }
    if (event == 0.4) { this.setState({ opacityValue: 0.4, opacityName: '40%' }); }
    if (event == 0.5) { this.setState({ opacityValue: 0.5, opacityName: '50%' }); }
    if (event == 0.6) { this.setState({ opacityValue: 0.6, opacityName: '60%' }); }
    if (event == 0.7) { this.setState({ opacityValue: 0.7, opacityName: '70%' }); }
    if (event == 0.8) { this.setState({ opacityValue: 0.8, opacityName: '80%' }); }
    if (event == 0.9) { this.setState({ opacityValue: 0.9, opacityName: '90%' }); }
    if (event == 1.0) { this.setState({ opacityValue: 1.0, opacityName: '100%' }); }

},
```

for loop it?

```
 for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
}
```

Comment: If `event` can only be one of these values, then there is no need to loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
handleOpacityThermatic(event) {
    const values = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0];

    values.forEach((val) => {
        if (event === val) {
            this.setState({
                opacityValue: val,
                opacityName: `${val * 10}%`
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the value of the event.

```
const eventValues = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0];

handleOpacityThermatic(event) {
   if (eventValues.includes(Number(event)) {
       this.setState({ opacityValue: event, opacityName: event*100 + '%' }); 
   }
},
```

or with string interpolation

```
handleOpacityThermatic(event) {
  if (eventValues.includes(Number(event)) {
     this.setState({ opacityValue: event, opacityName: `${event*100}%` });
  }
},
```

---

Thanks to kjonsson & Andrew Li for the kind reminder.

Comment: You have to handle the case where it isn't one of those values. He might not wanna set the state.

Comment: The array (or us a Set) can also be allocated outside the method. No need to allocate every time the method is called.